# Iphone-How to rotate image continuously for 30 secs and stop at 180 degrees

Tags: iphone, animation, ios6, xcode4.5

I have this so far. I want the image to rotate for about 30 seconds and come to a stop and then face the other way.

edit. Changed the code. I have this but it rotates and doesnt stop 180 degrees. I want it to rotate several times and come to stop in the opposite direction.

```
       CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
  animation.duration = 0.60;//animation.duration = 0.60;
  animation.repeatCount = 1;//animation.repeatCount = 1000ˆ

//#warning remove comment brackets below

  animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

  animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(degrees / 180)*M_PI], nil];

  animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

How can I stop the animation with the image still rotated 180 degrees.

Comment: The image is in a UIButton.

Comment: I have never used animations for layers, but isn't the duration property that you are setting to 1.1 the value that you want to set to 30 seconds?

Comment: For 30 secs : once you add a animation use [self performSelector:@selector(funct) withObject:nil afterDelay:30]; and call [yourview.layer removeAllAnimations]; in funct (selector), this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
animation.delegate = self;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatDuration = 30;
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-degreeToRadian(180)];
animation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:degreeToRadian(180)];
[self.button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

then add a delegate method

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
   self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreeToRadian(180));
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I've come up with the above but it doesnt stop at 180 degrees. Is my formula wrong.